# Mail::send() laravel 6 no muestra error pero no envia correo

Tags: laravel-6

Estoy creando un aplicación laravel y quiero enviar correo de confirmación al email del usuario cuando se registra usando un servidor smtp, lo estoy probando de forma local con homestead y no me muestra ningún error pero tampoco envía mensaje al correo.

Esta es mi función para enviar el correo:

```
public function sendemailtest($user_id){
        $user = User::where("id", "=", $user_id)->first();
        $data = array('name'=>$user->name, 'email' => $user->email); 
        Mail::send('emails.confirmation_code', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])->subject('Por favor confirma tu correo');
        });
        if (Mail::failures()) {
            return $this->sendResponse('fallo', "no se pudo enviar el mensaje");
        }else{
            return $this->sendResponse($data, "se envio correctamente");
        }
    }
```

Esta es la configuración de .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=midominio.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=miusuario
MAIL_PASSWORD=mipassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=correo@midominio.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Esta es la ruta:

```
Route::get('register/testemail/{user_id}', 'AuthController@sendemailtest');
```

Y lo pruebo con esta url:

```
http://me.pruebalocal.com:8000/register/testemail/1
```

Me devuelve esto:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
"name": "Cris Robles",
"email": "micorreo@gmai.com"
},
"message": "se envio correctamente"
}
```

Comment: Lo que podrías intentar es ocupar un correo tuyo ya existente , probar si se envía , si te muestra "message": "se envió correctamente" vas a revisar a tu bandeja de enviados para verificar que fue así , si no aparece nada revisa que si el puerto esta abierto. También si es que te envías el correo a un correo tuyo existente gmail demora unos minutos en llegar si que ojo ahí igual .
Espero encuentres la solución exacta. Suerte!

Comment: De hecho si lo he probado con mi correo personal solo que lo cambie para no mostrar mi correo  y cuando reviso la bandeja esta vacia

Comment: Intanta usar mailtrap para verificar si se envian tus correos